# Working with JSON retrieved via REST API in Python

Tags: python, json

I have the following in python:

```
import requests, json

cashboardapi = "http://api.cashboardapp.com/employees"
data = json.dumps({'name':'Cashboard', 'description':'Cashboard App API Request for Expenses'}) 
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(cashboardapi, data, headers=headers, auth=('SubDomain', 'API-KEY'))

mydata = r.json()

print(mydata)
```

I have changed the API keym (etc) so as not to expose personal info.

The output I get is:

```
[{u'last_name': u'Lastname', u'country_code': u'US', u'links': {u'manager_memberships': u'https://api.cashboardapp.com/employees/79164/manager_memberships', u'self': u'https://api.cashboardapp.com/employees/79164', u'project_assignments': u'https://api.cashboardapp.com/employees/79164/project_assignments'}, u'manager_memberships': [], u'is_archived': False, u'updated_at': u'2014-08-20T08:12:33-07:00', u'custom_1': u'', u'custom_2': u'', u'custom_3': u'', u'email_address': u'Chris@example.com', u'id': 79164, u'city': u'Any Town', u'first_name': u'Chris', u'employee_status_code': 2, u'zip': u'90210', u'state': u'HI', u'last_login': u'2014-08-20T08:12:33-07:00', u'address2': u'', u'login_count': 250, u'telephone': u'123-555-1234', u'address': u'55 Real Street Blvd', u'password': u'', u'url': u'', u'notes': u''}]
```

This appears to be a string, and I don't know how to proceed from there.
This gives me "in theory" the user ID of 79164, having that I would like to sum time entries for the current week.

Comment: You tagged this as Python 3, but your output shows you are actually using Python 2 here. Do make sure you use the correct Python syntax from here on out.

Answer (score 1):

You did not receive a string; `mydata` is a *list* with 1 entry in it, a dictionary.

To print the user id, you could access that one entry:

```
print mydata[0]['id']
```

When exploring responses like these, I always find the [`pprint.pprint()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to be very useful; it prints out such structures in a more readable fashion:

```
>>> pprint(mydata)
[{u'address': u'55 Real Street Blvd',
  u'address2': u'',
  u'city': u'Any Town',
  u'country_code': u'US',
  u'custom_1': u'',
  u'custom_2': u'',
  u'custom_3': u'',
  u'email_address': u'Chris@example.com',
  u'employee_status_code': 2,
  u'first_name': u'Chris',
  u'id': 79164,
  u'is_archived': False,
  u'last_login': u'2014-08-20T08:12:33-07:00',
  u'last_name': u'Lastname',
  u'links': {u'manager_memberships': u'https://api.cashboardapp.com/employees/79164/manager_memberships',
             u'project_assignments': u'https://api.cashboardapp.com/employees/79164/project_assignments',
             u'self': u'https://api.cashboardapp.com/employees/79164'},
  u'login_count': 250,
  u'manager_memberships': [],
  u'notes': u'',
  u'password': u'',
  u'state': u'HI',
  u'telephone': u'123-555-1234',
  u'updated_at': u'2014-08-20T08:12:33-07:00',
  u'url': u'',
  u'zip': u'90210'}]
```